# Dimensional analysis in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

From HMMT:

> Fifteen freshmen are sitting in a circle around a table, but the course assistant (who remains to stand) has made only six copies of today's handout. No freshman should get more than one handout and any freshman who does not get one should be able to read a neighbor's. If the freshman are distinguishable but the handouts are not, how many ways are there to distribute the six handouts subject to the above conditions?

The solution starts by considering the expected number of handouts to be received by any individual student. By linearity of expectation, there are 15 students and 6 handouts, so each student is expected to individually receive 6/15 handouts.

Then, for an arbitrary individual student S, we compute the number of distributions of handouts in which S receives a handout, called $y$. Also, let $x$ be the answer; $x$ is the number of ways to distribute the six handouts subject to the conditions of the problem.

Now, the solution states that $y=\frac{6}{15}x \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{15}{6}y$, which is how we shall find the answer. This feels nearly obvious because with $y=\frac{6}{15}x$ we're multiplying the # distributions by the expected number of handouts per student, but if we apply some kind of "dimensional analysis" to this, the multiplication does not turn out to something like "# distributions per student".

In particular, what would be the resulting meaning if we divided $x$ by the number of students as in $\frac{x}{15}$, rather than dividing $x$ by the number of students, then multiplying by the number of handouts, as we do with the equation $y=\frac{6}{15}x$?

Comment: I must not be understanding something about the solution.  There are $\binom{15}{6} = 5005$ ways to select $6$ out of $15$ students to receive a handout.  For any particular student $S$, $y = \binom{14}{5} = 2002$ ways result in $S$ receiving one of the handouts.  How can the correct answer be $x = \frac{15}{6}y = 5005$?

Comment: @BrianTung: There aren’t $\binom{15}6$ ways to distribute the handouts that ensure that each freshman either gets one or has a neighbor who gets one; $x<\binom{15}6$.

Comment: There are more conditions in selecting 6 out of the 15 students. "No freshman should get more than one handout and any freshman who does not get one should be able to read a neighbor's".

Comment: Ahh, OK.  I got the condition for the *answer*; what I didn't get was that that condition also applied to the count of $y$: "Then, for an arbitrary individual student S, we compute the number of distributions of handouts in which S receives a handout, called $y$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $\frac{6}{15}$ can be thought of as n expected value, but [in the solution](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2006/feb/comb/solutions.pdf), it is the probability that a student receives a handout, and probability is unitless.

Here's an equivalent way to phrase it, which may be easier to accept.

Let $x$ be the overall number of solutions, and let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{15}$ be the number of solutions in which student $1, 2, \dots, 15$ respectively gets a handout. The solution shows that $x_i = 50$ for any $i$.

If we add up $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{15}$, then each solution is counted $6$ times, because in each solution, $6$ students get handouts. Therefore
$$
     x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{15} = 6x \implies 15 \cdot 50 = 6x \implies x = \frac{15}{6} \cdot 50 = 125.
$$

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why must we do anything more past finding that the $x_i=50$ for $1 \le i \le 15$? This number takes into account the conditions of the problem; the fact that each student must be able to view a handout is accounted for. Why is the answer not 50?

Comment: The number $x_i$ is not the number of solutions in which student $i$ *is able to view* a handout; it's the number of solutions in which student $i$ *is physically holding* a handout. There are other solutions in which student $i$ doesn't have a handout, but is looking at a neighbor's.