# Why does $6$ students getting handouts imply each solution counted $6$ times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is the following question here:
[Dimensional analysis in combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726889/dimensional-analysis-in-combinatorics)

> Fifteen freshmen are sitting in a circle around a table, but the course assistant (who remains to stand) has made only six copies of today's handout. No freshman should get more than one handout and any freshman who does not get one should be able to read a neighbor's. If the freshman are distinguishable but the handouts are not, how many ways are there to distribute the six handouts subject to the above conditions?

It's from the HMMT competition, official problem and solution can be found here: https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2006/feb/comb/solutions.pdf

Misha Lavrov writes in his answer:

> Let $x$ be the overall number of solutions, and let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{15}$ be the number of solutions in which student $1, 2, \dots, 15$ respectively gets a handout. The solution shows that $x_i = 50$ for any $i$. If we add up $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{15}$, then each solution is counted $6$ times, because in each solution, $6$ students get handouts. Therefore$$
>      x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{15} = 6x \implies 15 \cdot 50 = 6x \implies x = \frac{15}{6} \cdot 50 = 125.$$

However, I don't see how "in each solution, $6$ students get handouts" implies that "each solution is counted $6$ times". Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It is similar to saying that on a cube each edge connects $2$ vertices and there are $12$ edges, but there are not $2\times 24$ vertices.  Since each vertex has $3$ edges, there are $\frac{2\times 24}{3} = 8$ vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose students $a,b,c,d,e$ and $f$ get handouts. This is just one solution. But, in $\sum x_i$, this will be counted $6$ times, once when we focus on $a$ (i.e., the $x_i$ where $a$ is initially given a handout), then $b$, then $c$, and likewise. The same can be said for every other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we play through all $x$ solutions, and each time additionally hand out a token to each student obtaining a handout with that solution; they keep the tokens but return the handout before we do the same with the next of the $x$ solutions. Then the total number of tokens given out is $6x$ because we give out $6$ tokens for each of the $x$ solutions.

The number of tokens the $i$th student finally holds is what the quoted solution calls $x_i$, so $\sum_i x_i=6x$.